# How to move object to a specific point using physics in unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I need an object to move to the spcific point. During the movement it must detect collisions (atleast raycast).

Using `addForce`, object's movement is inaccurate and cannot stop at the specific point. `MovePosition` is used for kinematic objects(maybe i am wrong, but it doesn't work for my dynamic object).

Any ideas how that can be possible?

Comment: It's pretty much the same thing if you translate the position of the rigid body using `rigidbody.position` or anything of the like. `MovePosition` was made specifically to deal with this oscillation of the two bodies in conjunction with active physics. CPU overhead is negligible in this case, since `MovePosition` was made specifically for this purpose.

Comment: It works, however the object stops around 0.01 before point and i cannot check if vectors are equal ,but if there is no other option, i'll deal with it using some more if statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MovePosition with non kinematic objects
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html

```
rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

They will interact with triggers and collisions. If the rigidbody is kinematic then any collisions won't affect the rigidbody itself and will only affect any other dynamic colliders.

Comment: Notably using rb2d.MovePosition on a dynamic collider is the equivalent of changing transform.position. Many times this is adequate despite all the back and forth on this all over.

Answer (score 0):

**1** Move object from point A to point B
Use **MoveTowards2D**:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html

**2** To detect collisions
Use **OnTriggerEnter2D** or **OnCollisionEnter2D**: 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html

So in that case, you got:

-one gameObject who **moves from A**

-one gameObject who **acts as a wall**

-one gameObject which is **your B point.**

You need to attach this script to the gameObject that wants to move from point A to point B:

```
public class MoveTo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform pointToGo;
    public float speed;

    public bool colliding = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!colliding)
        {
            //Move
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, pointToGo.position, step);
        }

    }

    //Callback when enter the trigger
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        colliding = true;

    }
}
```

***Note:*** Remember that both, the gameObject with the script, and the wall, should have collider and rigidbody attached. Also if you want to use the trigger, remember to check "Is Trigger" on your wall collider.